# How to implement Edit & Delete Functionality in Tablecell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

In my app,

I want to imaplement the  edit  & delete functionality on table Cell.

[image]

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this tutorial to get started it also has code to download.
http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/

Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods in `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDataDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

See also documenatation [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)